# How many records created for each day of the week this year?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, date-arithmetic

I have about 50k rows in a Postgres database that are users and when they signed up.

I am trying to understand how many users sign up for each day of the week since the start of the year, e.g.:

```
1238 on Monday
3487 on Tuesday
1237 on Wednesday
```

Example date entry: `'2014-10-31 17:17:30.138579'`

Answer (score 2):

A plain aggregate query after extracting the weekday. You could use [`to_char()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) to get the (English by default) weekday:

```
SELECT to_char(created_at, 'Day'), count(*) AS ct
FROM   tbl
WHERE  created_at >= date_trunc('year', now())
GROUP  BY 1;
```

If performance is important, [`EXTRACT()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) is slightly faster:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM created_at), count(*) AS ct
FROM   tbl
WHERE  created_at >= date_trunc('year', now())
GROUP  BY 1;
```

1 .. Monday, ... , 7 .. Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the EXTRACT(DOW from timestamp) to determined the day of the week. 0 is Sunday. 6 is Saturday.

Example:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM TIMESTAMP '2015-06-22 20:38:40');
```

Result is 1 (Monday)